# Sending data with GET in JSF

Tags: html, jsf

I have a search form on my website that I build with what I learn in the book I am reading and I have a question about the "name"-part of the query parameters.

After what I have understood I use normal HTML form when I want to send data with GET and I use the `<h:inputText id="city" value="#{testBean.city}" />` these tags inside. It is correct that what you normally would write with `name="city"` in normal HTML tags is the same as `id="city"`? And it applies for all JSF tags?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's right. As far as I know, when you write tags with no 'id' attribute, the Renderer generates a automatic 'name' attribute for the corresponding HTML component/tag/smth. But when you register a jsf component with an 'id' attribute, its value is used for the value for the 'name' in the HTML.